# Node: Updating DB with PUT not working for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My `GET` returns an array of 2 simple objects from the DB:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60491b5741893d23216d2de3",
        "text": "test`",
        "score": 19,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-10T19:17:43.809Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "604947c7b3a7ed28c43c05b7",
        "text": "HELLO",
        "score": 22,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-10T22:27:19.739Z"
    }
]
```

In Postman, I am trying to do a PUT to `/604947c7b3a7ed28c43c05b7` to update that post.  In the body, I am sending:

```
{
    "text": "Updated post test",
    "score": 100
}
```

and my node route looks like this:

```
   router.put('/:id', async(req,res) => {
        const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
        const post = {};
        if (req.body.text) post.text = req.body.text;
        if (req.body.score) post.score = req.body.score;
    
        await posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.id },
            { $set: post },
            { new: true }
          );
        res.status(200).send();
    })
```

I am getting a success message back but when I do a `GET` to see the array, the value hasn't changed for that post.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're using the native mongodb node driver. In mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` will not actually execute the query unless a callback function is passed. I don't know this with full certainly, but it sounds like the native driver works the same way. So you would have to rewrite your code like so:

```
posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.id },
            { $set: post },
            { new: true },
            result => {console.log(result)}
          );
```

Another way to do it is by appending `.then()` to the end, because [according to the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate), it return a promise if no callback is passed. So here is how I would do it:

```
await posts.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.id },
            { $set: post },
            { new: true }
          ).then(r => r);
```